# How to do GROUP BY and COUNT(*) in JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have tables named  company, product, purchase_order, skid, process_record and I want MySQL query result as below.

[image]

I tried

```
SELECT s.id as skidId, s.skidBarcode, po.poNumber, s.companyId, c.companyName, p.productId , p.productName, totalProcessed 
FROM skid s 
INNER JOIN company c ON s.companyId = c.id 
INNER JOIN purchase_order po on s.purchaseOrderId = po.id 
INNER JOIN product prdct on p.productId = prdct.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT skidID, productId , COUNT(*) as processedQuantity FROM process_record GROUP BY productId ) p ON p.skidID= s.id 
WHERE s.status = 'closed' ORDER By s.companyId,s.id
```

However, this query result gives processedQuantity count NULL and random wrong count on some rows.

How can I get the desired MySQL query output as shown in screenshot?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `GROUP BY skidID, productId` instead of `GROUP BY productId` and it resolved the issue.

```
 SELECT s.id as skidId, s.skidBarcode, po.poNumber, s.companyId, c.companyName, p.productId , p.productName, totalProcessed 
    FROM skid s 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT skidID, productId , COUNT(*) as processedQuantity FROM process_record GROUP BY skidID, productId ) p ON p.skidID= s.id 
    INNER JOIN company c ON s.companyId = c.id 
    INNER JOIN purchase_order po on s.purchaseOrderId = po.id 
    INNER JOIN product prdct on p.productId = prdct.id 
    
    WHERE s.status = 'closed' ORDER By s.companyId,s.id
```

Comment: SELECT s.id as skidId, s.barCode, po.orderNumber, s.skidContent, s.companyId, s.close_status, c.companyName, IFNULL(p.productId,0) as productId, IFNULL(p.processedQuantity,0) as processedQuantity FROM skid s 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT skidID, productId , COUNT(*) as processedQuantity FROM process_record GROUP BY skidID, productId ) p ON p.skidID= s.id 
INNER JOIN company c ON s.companyId = c.id 
INNER JOIN purchase_order po on s.purchaseOrderId = po.id 
WHERE s.close_status != 'ClosedAndInvoiced' 
ORDER By s.companyId,s.id